# Can I bid on AdWords Keyword Tool with no competition?

Tags: keywords, google-ads, ppc

I am very new to PPC, and I want to advertise a product. The problem is, the relevant keywords I find are very low traffic (~100/mo) and have no competition at all, and not even CPC estimate, or maybe 5c.

Will I be able to bid on those keywords and have my ad display in the search result or will Google only allow ads if there is sufficient competition?

If Google estimates 5c/click is this real or will it be more like 5$/click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I be able to bid on those keywords and have my ad display in the search result or will Google only allow ads if there is sufficient competition?

You will be able to bid on those keywords.

> If Google estimates 5c/click is this real or will it be more like 5$/click?

There is a difference between what the Keyword Planner estimates and the estimates you'll get when you ad your keywords to an group. Add "Est. first page bid" from Columns-->Attributes and you'll find how much is the bid for your keywords to appear on the first page. These estimates also change depending on the total bidding for that keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Google allows bids on keywords with no competition but it sets a minimum bid that you are allowed to make.  The minimum bid depends on your quality score for that ad.   Since quality score is mainly determined by click through rate, your initial minimum bid may be high until Google has enough data to assign you a good quality score.   When bidding on a keyword with no competition, the more people that click your ad (better CTR), the less you will pay per click.

Comment: So i found a keyword with 0.08€ per click estimate in keywords tool and 500 exact searches monthly. do you think I would be able to get clicks for this for 8c each? assuming i have a kick ass landing page optimized for the keyword